# How much does the price of a new bicycle drop a year after buying it?

Tags: frugal, price

I'm planning to buy a bicycle "on a budget" (I'm sure yet if I should buy a new or an old one). But since I'm going to use for just a year, I'm wondering how much I'm going to sell it for next year (how much I'm going to lose in it purchase price)?

I don't know if what they say about cars (that you lose `20%` of a new car's value after owning it for a year according to [Car Depreciation: How Much Have You Lost?](https://www.trustedchoice.com/insurance-articles/wheels-wings-motors/car-depreciation/)) applies also to bicycles.

Comment: Depends what kind of riding you want to do, and how you want to store the bike.    For commuting and health, a used bike is ideal.    A used bike, budget on $0 value at the end, and anything you get for it is a win.

Comment: Note that you're likely to save about 1/3rd on last year's model, or this years model at the end of the biking season, vs what you'd pay new in the spring.  But for your situation *used* is definitely better.

Comment: As to what you can get for a bought-new bike after a year's moderately heavy use, I certainly wouldn't count on more than 50%, regardless of how you time things.

Comment: The biggest problem with the 2nd hand bicycle market is volume. For cars, the market is relatively stable, given that there are many buyer/sellers. Given the size of the market (and stolen bikes), it is much more of a "buyer's market". In many cities there are bike shops which specialize in selling the same bike many times (and buying it back again afterwards) to people in your exact position.

Comment: You need to understand that many bike stores don't sell their entire stock of new bikes in a year. So in 2018, if I hunt around, I can find a brand new 2017 model for sale at many bike shops. At a great discount, and it's new, and it has a warranty. So your used bike has to be priced less than this to sell. Your wear & tear on it will also decrease its value.

Answer (score 6):

I would use bicycle blue book as a way to figure out the change in value of the bike.  They have a system to estimate the resale value of used bikes.  Your bikes condition at the end of the year will matter so keep it clean and lubed.

Comment: They're just estimates and they can be *way* off for a particular market.

Answer (score 5):

This is sooooooooooo wide open.  You lose like 1/3 rolling it out the door.

Condition matters more than years.  If it 10 years old with some out of date components that matters. But 3 versus 5 does not matter.

I buy used nice bikes and never pay more than 1/3 *retail*.  Sometimes you can get a new bike for 80% *retail* at end of season.

I could sell every used bike I own for what I paid for it.

If you are using it for a year then used.  If you know nothing about bikes then you might get ripped off.

High end bikes lose value faster.  A $200 BSO is not going to lose 1/3 out the door but it is still not worth $100.  Best value is picking up like a $1200 bike for $400 or even pay $400 for a $900 bike.  They are cleaning out the garage.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should opt for a used one, but I need to learn more about bikes. 1/3 retail price is surely very tempting.

Comment: For other readers - MTB's have changed quite a lot in the last 5 or so years, More than about 5 years old age is now affecting price more than ever - two edge sword, great bikes in good condition at around 20% of what they were retail, but parts are harder to find. (e.g. Try to find a half decent 9mm QR 1 1/8th straight steerer fork today.)